# An extra USB icon on taskabr

Tags: windows-7, usb, icons

I have an extra USB icon on my system tray in Win 7. I have the vmware installed on this machine. The USB icon shows my HDD drives!
I think it appeared when I uninstalled Intel Rapid Storage Technology (IRST) app. I uninstalled it because I wouldn't think that IRST does anything useful on my desktop PC.
Now for getting rid of that extra icon do I need to reinstall that IRST!? What does it do actually in my PC please?

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: Do you mean the "Safely remove hardware" icon?

Comment: I have only 1 grade! And can't use of screenshots :(

Comment: Yes, I meant that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is visible because SATA controller's driver reports drives as removable. It's only a cosmetic issue, though: Windows won't really let you eject HDDs, an error message will appear if you try to.

If you really don't like that icon, then your best bet is to install IRST back.

Comment: And how to find the desired IRST driver for installing please?

Comment: Find your motherboard on its manufacturer's website and go to Downloads, IRST should be there. You can also try to get it from Intel's website.